# how to Integrate firebase cloud functions, firestore, and google bigtable

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-bigtable

the docs for firestore say it doesn't support aggregation queries naturally and one of the options we should use is cloud function triggers (to precalculate values we can retrieve using simple query)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation#solution_cloud_functions

I want to do more advanced analytics and was thinking bigtable/bigquery might be a good fit.

How do i go about calling gcp products from a firebase cloud function? (i assume it's possible)

I can't seem to find any docs on this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Firebase cloud functions are built on top of "regular" [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), in which case this example should help you get started with using Bigtable in that environment:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/node/cloud-functions